# Android FusedLocationClient with PendingIntent not receiving location update when app is in background

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I'm using FusedLocationClient and broadcast receiver to get location in background, i enabled background location background permission and locations (FINE and COARSE) permission. i receive location update when app in foreground but when moving app in background i don't receive any update.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
        android:name=".LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.test.gpstracking.LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

LocationManager Class

class MyLocationManager private constructor(private val context: Context) {

```
// The Fused Location Provider provides access to location APIs.
private val fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient =
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
private val TAG = "MyLocationManager"

// Stores parameters for requests to the FusedLocationProviderApi.
private val locationRequest: LocationRequest = LocationRequest().apply {
    interval = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(4)
    fastestInterval = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(4)
    priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
}

/**
 * Creates default PendingIntent for location changes.
 *
 * Note: We use a BroadcastReceiver because on API level 26 and above (Oreo+), Android places
 * limits on Services.
 */
private val locationUpdatePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
    var intent = Intent(context, LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
    intent.action = LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
}

@Throws(SecurityException::class)
@MainThread
fun startLocationUpdates() {
    Log.d(TAG, "startLocationUpdates()")

    if (!context.hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) return

    try {
        Log.e(TAG, "receiving location updates")
        // If the PendingIntent is the same as the last request (which it always is), this
        // request will replace any requestLocationUpdates() called before.
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationUpdatePendingIntent)
    } catch (permissionRevoked: SecurityException) {

        Log.e(TAG, "not receiving location updates")

        // Exception only occurs if the user revokes the FINE location permission before
        // requestLocationUpdates() is finished executing (very rare).
        Log.d(TAG, "Location permission revoked; details: $permissionRevoked")
        throw permissionRevoked
    }
}


companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: MyLocationManager? = null

    fun getInstance(context: Context): MyLocationManager {
        return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            INSTANCE ?: MyLocationManager(context).also { INSTANCE = it }
        }
    }
}
```

}

My broadcast receiver

```
 class LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
private val TAG = "LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver"
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    
    if (intent.action == ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES) {

        // Checks for location availability changes.
        LocationAvailability.extractLocationAvailability(intent)?.let { locationAvailability ->
            if (!locationAvailability.isLocationAvailable) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Location services are no longer available!")
            }
        }

        LocationResult.extractResult(intent)?.let { locationResult ->
            locationResult.lastLocation
            val location = locationResult.lastLocation
            if (location != null) {
                Toast.makeText(context, location.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS : I'm following the android source code of LocationUpdatesBackgroundKotlin from google repo on github -> [link](https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/main/LocationUpdatesBackgroundKotlin)

Answer (score -2):

Android does not allow any kind of background service after Android Oreo, Check out this link will guide you.
[Access Location in Background](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background)